# Intercept asp:LInkButton postback for client side confirmation dialog?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I want to inject a confirmation dialog to allow the user to cancel the click before the postback occurs.

What's the cleanest way?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Btn_RemoveContractPeriod" Text="Remove" 
runat="server" OnClick="OnRemoveContractPeriod_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Btn_RemoveContractPeriod" Text="Remove" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Message')"/>
```

Comment: but how then do i hook it up so after confirmation postbacks and calls the server code?

Comment: If confirm function returns false, the __doPostback wont be called. otherwise, click event will raise.